# Phone doesn't send all stored ssids while capturing Wi-Fi probe wequests

Tags: request, wifi, broadcast, ssid, probe

I build a script with scapy to capture probe requests in a monitornig wi-fi interface. 
I successfully capture the requests, and some of the SSIDs contained in them. But most of the networks stored in the phone don't get broadcasted.
And there isn't a clear pattern of why this happens. Some phones don't broadcast ssids at all.

I'm trying to find an explanation for the reasoning behind this behaviour, but haven't found any, apart that the hidden networks should be broadcasted in order for the phone to connect to them, but even that is not true, and most of the broadcasted ones are visible.

Another behaviour is the iPhones, that only seem to broadcast the network that they are connected to, and nothing else. (no network -> no SSIDs).

I have tried putting the interface in various channels, and results vary on the broadcasted networks, but the great majority of the saved ones in the device still aren't broadcasted.

Is there a reason behind this? Or a way to force the device to broadcast them all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to assume that the phone would do a probe request for each and every known network, permanently.

This is *not* the case - and not just for phone, but in general. Quoting the Wi-Fi Alliance[*]:

> What are passive and active scanning?
>
> The reason for client scanning is to determine a suitable AP to which
>   the client *may* [emphasis mine] need to roam now or in the future. A client can use two
>   scanning methods: active and passive. **During an active scan, the
>   client radio transmits a probe request and listens for a probe
>   response from an AP** [emphasis mine]. *With a passive scan, the
>   client radio listens on each channel for beacons*[emphasis mine again]
>   sent periodically by an AP. A passive scan generally takes more time,
>   since the client must listen and wait for a beacon versus actively
>   probing to find an AP. Another limitation with a passive scan is that
>   if the client does not wait long enough on a channel, then the client
>   may miss an AP beacon.

So this is entirely application/OS dependent if

- the phone STA do an active scan, sending probe requests,
- or just seat there listening for beacons (or doing nothing at all).

In my remembering - it's been a few years I didn't worked/looked at Android code, so it may have change - Android will *not* do an active scan, and thus will *not* send probe request to known SSID, *unless* you're in the Wi-Fi networks setting screen. It will just listen to beacons.

There are some Wi-Fi 802.11 design rationale behind this:

- STA are supposed to be mobile. After all, if you're not moving from
  time to time, there's not much point in using Wi-Fi (except marketing
  or laziness, and of course smartphones changed that), you might as
  well get wired.
- ...if you're mobile, it's reasonable to think you're running on a
  battery,
- And so you want to save battery life: so you'll rather do passive
  scans listening to beacons rather than active scan sending probe
  request, because this uses less power.

This idea of power saving alternative capabilities is spread all other the place in 802.11 design, hidden under carpet, when you're a STA.

So it is fully OS stack/application dependent from the STA if it 1/ just listen to beacons /2 actively send probe-request for every know AP 3/ send a broadcast probe-request, and also if it do so in a continuous manner, or periodically, or depending if it's in a know state (ex screen ON, and user going to the Wi-Fi networks setting screen).

Now there may be some other considerations, like some regional regulations that mandate that you first listen to beacons to decide if you can or cannot use some channels. But the main point is above.

*:

http://www.wi-fi.org/knowledge-center/faq/what-are-passive-and-active-scanning

**EDIT:**

**On the programming side:**

1/ What you seem to have is an IOP (interoperability) problem, because you expect a specific behavior from STA regarding scanning active vs passive and the involved probe-requests, and this is not how it works in the real world. Depending on your application final main goal, this may be a flawn in the design - or just a minor nuisance. You may want to restrict yourself to some specific device's brand, or try to cover all cases, which has a development cost.

2/ ...OR you were just surprised by your observations, and look for an explanation. In such case of surprising results, it goes without saying: go straight to wireshark to check your program observations (if your program is a packet sniffer) or behavior (if your program is a client/server/layer XYZ protocol implementation).

**On the 802.11 strategies regarding active vs passive scan and power saving:**

From "802.11 Wireless Networks: The Definitive Guide, 2nd Edition", by Matthew S. Gast ("member of the IEEE 802.11 working group, and serves as chair of 802.11 Task Group M. As chair of the Wi-Fi Alliance's Wireless Network Management marketing task group, he is leading the investigation of certification requirements for power saving, performance optimization, and location and timing services" - from his publisher bio). A book i can highly recommend.

p. 171:

> ScanType (active or passive)
>
> Active scanning uses the transmission of Probe Request frames to
>   identify networks in the area. Passive scanning saves battery power by
>   listening for Beacon frames.

p. 172:

> Passive Scanning
>
> Passive scanning saves battery power because it does not require
>   transmitting. In passive scanning, a station moves to each channel on
>   the channel list and waits for Beacon frames.

Also, a bit old (2003), but these guys know their stuff about networking. About scanning strategies:

From Cisco "802.11 Wireless LAN Fundamentals", chapter 5 "mobility".

Page 153:

> Roaming Algorithms
>
> The mechanism to determine when to roam is not defined by the IEEE
>   802.11 specification and is, therefore, left to vendors to implement. [...] The fact that the algorithms are left to vendor implementation
>   provide vendors an opportunity to differentiate themselves by creating
>   new and better performing algorithms than their competitors. Roaming
>   algorithms become a vendor’s “secret sauce,” and as a result are kept
>   confidential.

Page 154 "Determining Where to Roam":

> There is no ideal technique for scanning. Passive scanning has the
>   benefit of not requiring  the client to transmit probe requests but
>   runs the risk of potentially missing an AP because it might not
>   receive a beacon during the scanning duration. Active scanning has the
>   benefit of actively seeking out APs to associate to but requires the
>   client to actively transmit probes.  Depending on the implementation
>   for the 802.11 client, one might be better suited than the other. *For
>   example, many embedded systems use passive scanning as the preferred
>   method* [emphasis mine] [...]

Other interesting stuff on page 155, "Preemptive AP Discovery".

Comment: hmm, I see. But btw, when I said "Some phones don't broadcast ssids at all.", all the ones I tested broadcasted probe requests.
And from what I've read before, the active scan is more battery efficient than the passive one, thus its invention.

Comment: Also, isn't active discovery a must to connect to hidden networks?
But from what I see, even some of the hidden networks are not being broadcasted

Comment: This is another question, but "hidden networks" is a ridiculous false security measure, that you should not care about, nor the users foolish enough to configure their AP as such. It's just a trick that rely on the fact that SSID are plain 32 bytes, no string termination or nothing, no UTF-8 or any encoding, so they may as well be "carriage-returns + line-feeds + tabs + spaces" only. Or just 32 '0' bytes. There's no such thing as "hidden SSID".

Comment: "hiden networks": SO BTW, since you're using Scapy/Python, you **must** handled SSIDs as bytearray of 32 bytes. **Not** as a string, ascii or whatever. Otherwise you have a bug. And I hope Scapy does this too.

Comment: thanks, I just tested with Wireshark, and the broadcasted networks captured are the same as the ones captured by Scapy.
I wasn't aware of the string vs byte representation, but everything has gone well so far on that department, and the information is the same as wireshark, so I assume that scapy is doing the right job